# Image Move & Resize not working when using a custom camera overlay iPhone SDK 3.1+

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.1

I used to use the old-school method of adding an overlay to the camera screen, and that worked fine.  However, since 3.1 came out, Apple is insisting that I use the API to add an overlay.  I quickly got the overlay to work, but it seems that if I use the custom overlay, then the move & resize screen is not responsive, I can only use or retake, can't actually resize & move.  The code I am using is below.  I have tried several variations, but the only thing that actually enables the move & resize is to remove the line that adds the custom overlay view.

Any ideas?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"camera-template-long.png"];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)] ;
imgView.image = image;

UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
overlayView.opaque = NO;
[overlayView addSubview:imgView];

UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;        
picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
picker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire issue goes away once you use `[overlayView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];` to stop the overlay view from handling the input.

Comment: then why need overlay? i tried doing what suggested above, the overlay won't show up afterwards.

Comment: I only need the overlay to display a frame over the live camera view. I don't need any user interaction in my overlay.

Answer (score 3):

Set both `allowsEditing`/`showsCameraControls` properties to NO, prepare your original view to `cameraOverlayView`, and use `takePicture` method.

Then, `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` will be called directly.

---

Please try the following code:

```
- (void)foo {
  UIImagePickerController *controller = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease]; 
  controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
  controller.cameraOverlayView = self.cameraOverlay; 
  [self performSelector:@selector(moveOverlayViewToSublayer:) withObject:controller afterDelay:0.1f]; 
  controller.delegate = self; 
  [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]; 
}
- (void) moveOverlayViewToSublayer:(UIImagePickerController*)controller { 
  CALayer *aLayer = self.cameraOverlay.layer.superlayer; 
  controller.cameraOverlayView = nil; 
  [aLayer addSublayer:self.cameraOverlay.layer]; 
}
```

I hope it will work well.

Comment: This still allows resize and move?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Your question is "How to activate resize&crop operation when a custom overlay is added?", isn't it? I have changed my answer.

Comment: This worked, with a subtle change, I needed to keep both allowsEditing and showsCameraControls set to YES.  Thanks.  Now let's see if Apple will approve it.  I get a warning that CALayer addSublayer is not valid.

Comment: I would say no. It didn't work on all version and the selected answer actually did what I needed.

Comment: @Katokichi: How to get overlay frame size whenever move new frame?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.techques.com/question/1-10178214/cameraOverlayView-prevents-editing-with-allowsEditing

This works perfectly for me. I tried to disable userInteractionEnabled but in vain.